# Foreign Key constraint on a @OneToMany relationship

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I want to make sure I understand what I am doing in my DB representation & with hibernate.

My project management tool lets my user create a `Project` that is composed of `Phase`(s).

I do not wish to create a link table and have proceeded like such in my entities:

My `ProjectEntity`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
private Set<PhaseEntity> phases = new HashSet<>(0);
```

and my `PhaseEntity`:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class)
private ProjectEntity project;
```

After filling up my `PhaseEntity` and saving it via my `DAO`

`phaseDao.save(phaseEntity);`

I get the following error:

> ERROR: insert or update on table "phase" violates foreign key constraint "fk8x1x98c4hq4ps0d30y6nxe90u"
>     Detail: Key (phase_id)=(1820) is not present in table "project".

The way I see it, pushing a phase containing a specific `ProjectEntity` to my database should create 1 entry and update another one, the first should be my `phase` entry, and the latter should be an update to a `project` by adding a phase to its `Set`.

Do I have to explicitly save my phase in my `project` table?
Do yo see any flaws in my reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing the knowledge!

"a Project that is composed of Phase(s)"
So , if you want to insert a phase in "Phase" table, you need to have a role in Project table which has the same 'class' column value as "class" column value of newly inserted row in Phase table.

A foreign key is a column (or columns) that references a column (most often the primary key) of another table. The purpose of the foreign key is to ensure referential integrity of the data. In other words, only values that are supposed to appear in the database are permitted.

We have two tables, a Project table that includes all projects, and a Phase table that includes all phases. A Project that is composed of Phase(s). To enforce this logic, we place a foreign key on the Phase table and have it reference the primary key of the Project table. This way, we can ensure that all phases in the Phase table are related to a project in the Phase table. In other words, the Phases table cannot contain information on a project that is not in the Project table.